# UIImageView inside UIScrollView positioning issue after rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a UIImageView inside a UIScrollView and it rotates perfectly fine if I don't zoom in and rotate. However if I were zoomed in and rotate then the position would be messy. Why is this? How do I solve this? I think the size of the image is fine, it's just the position?

One thing I tried doing is do the following:

```
[imageScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

and this fixed the issue, however I can no longer zoom in after rotating it.

Comment: I'm experiencing that same problem. Hope someone helps.

Comment: I actually solved this issue by setting the zoomSize back to 1 when rotating the device

Comment: There is no zoomSize property in a UIScrollView. Do you mean zoomScale, I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable autoresize of subviews on the scrollview.

When the orientation changes, the scrollview gets rotated and resized. The resize has an impact depending on the autoresize subviews property of the scrollview (true/false), and the autoresizemask of the contents of the scrollview.

If you're using IB, uncheck "Autoresize subviews" on the scrollview, or from code, set `self.scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = NO;` (replace `scrollView` with the property referring to your scrollview)

Answer (score -1):

You want to reset the content size and frame after the rotation's happened.

```
 - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    self.scrollView.contentSize = self.photoView.image.size;
    self.photoView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.photoView.image.size.width, self.photoView.image.size.height);
}
```